# Tailwind classes are not working locally; without CDN when loaded offline. Developed in PHP

Tags: php, localhost, tailwind-css, glob, cdn

I have followed step-by-step guide on `https://tailwindcss.com` but when I try to run my project offline or simply try to comment `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>`, some classes fail to load. Can someone please help me with getting Tailwind working locally Please have a look at my project structure below:

[image: tailwind project structure with PHP]

I last edit I made was adding more file types in the content module. Please check below:

> tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,ts,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I have tried changing path as per the Php structure accordingly but that doesn't work either. Please check below:

> header.php

```
<?php?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="htmltag" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>
    <?php
      if (isset($title)) {
        echo$title . " ~Hello";
      }
      else {
        echo"Helllo";
      }
    ?>
  </title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <link href="../dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>      
<script defer src='alpine.js'></script>
    
  <meta name="description" content="lorem I[sum ] lorem I[sum ]lorem I[sum ]" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="lorem, ipsum" />
```